# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable without Python keywords in variable names

Tags: python, p5.js

I'm new to coding, it's been a long time since I last coded,
I did it all of a sudden because of a school assignment.

I know my coding is a terrible code covered in 'global', but I'm too noob to fix it, so I gave up.
I'm only going to use this as a demonstration of how it works in school, so it doesn't matter how it's coded as long as it works.

I know that this error occurs when I put Python keywords in a variable,
Python keywords in the variable are nowhere to be found no matter how much I look for them.
am i blind?

> line 44, in draw     springforceY = -springconst(positionY - headposY) TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

```
#importing module
from p5 import *
import builtins
def exit(): # to fix p5.exit exception(not working)
    builtins.exit()

#initial var
gravity = 20
mass = 15
forceY = 0
forceX = 0
springforceY = 0
springforceX = 0
accY = 0
accX = 0
positionY = 100
positionX = 75
velocityY = 0
velocityX = 0
timeGap = 0.2
headpositionY = 110
headpositionX = 80
springconst = 2
#setup(): initial canvas setting
def setup():
    size(400,400) 
    fill(0)

    
    
#draw(): loop after setup()
def draw():
    global springforceX
    global springforceY
    global velocityY
    global velocityX
    global positionY
    global positionX
    global accY
    global accX
    global forceY
    global forceX
    #calculating
    springforceY = -springconst(positionY - headpositionY) # <<< line 44
    springforceX = -springconst(positionX - headpositionX)
    forceY = mass * gravity + springforceY
    forceX = springforceX    
    accY = forceY/mass
    accX = forceX/mass
    velocityY = velocityY + accY * timeGap 
    velocityX = velocityX + accX * timeGap
    positionY = positionY + velocityY * timeGap
    positionX = positionX + velocityX * timeGap
     
    #showing
    background(255, 255, 255)
    ellipse(200, positionY, 20, 20)
    ellipse(headpositionX - 5, headpositionY - 5, 10, 10 )
    line(positionX, positionY, headpositionX, headpositionY)
    text("gravity : "+str(gravity), (0,40))
    text("mass : "+str(mass), (0,50))
    text("accelrationY : "+str(accY), (0,60))
    text("accelrationX : "+str(accX), (0,70))
    if mouse_button == 'CENTER': # press wheel button to restart
        velocityY = 0
        velocityX = 0
        positionY = 100
        positionX = 75


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Comment: do you mean multiplying the springconst?  `springforceY = -springconst * (positionY - headpositionY)`

Comment: You have springconst defined at the top as an integer (2), but on line 44 you're trying to call it as if it were a function using ().

Comment: happened to me, mixing engineering maths and coding :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's maths multiplication, the code should be

```
springforceY = -springconst * (positionY - headpositionY) # <<< line 44
springforceX = -springconst * (positionX - headpositionX)
```